# groupby aggregation on day level of date time column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below. Which is a doctors booking data.

```
  Doctor     Appointment              Show
  A          2020-01-18 12:00:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-18 12:30:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00      No
  A          2020-01-18 13:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-18 12:00:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-18 12:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-18 13:00:00      No
  B          2020-01-18 13:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-18 16:00:00      No
  B          2020-01-18 16:30:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-19 12:30:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00      No
  A          2020-01-19 13:30:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00      Yes
  A          2020-01-19 14:30:00      No
  A          2020-01-19 16:00:00      No
  A          2020-01-19 16:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-19 12:00:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-19 12:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-19 13:00:00      No
  B          2020-01-19 13:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-19 14:00:00      No
  B          2020-01-19 14:30:00      Yes
  B          2020-01-19 15:00:00      No
  B          2020-01-18 15:30:00      Yes
```

From the above dataframe I would like to create a function in pandas, which will output the following.

I tried below

```
def Doctor_date_summary(doctor, date):
   Number of slots = df.groupby([doctor, date] ).sum()
```

Expected Output:

```
Doctor_date_summary(Doctor, date)
If Doctor = A, date = 2020-01-19

Number of slots = 8
Number of show up = 5
show up percentage = 62.5
```

where number of Yes = 5 in show column on that date for that docto

Comment: One question - Do you need count all data like in my question and then seelct by date and doctors? Or need select only some values and count like another question?

Comment: Need to select only some values and count like another.

Comment: not all only some selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create each mask separately in function, then chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and `sum` for count:

```
df['Appointment'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment'])

def Doctor_date_summary(doctor, date):
    m1 = df['Doctor'] == doctor
    m2 = df['Appointment'].dt.normalize() == date
    m3 = df['Show'] == 'Yes'
    show_up = (m1 & m2 & m3).sum()
    no = (m1 & m2).sum()
    return show_up, no

up, no = Doctor_date_summary('A', '2020-01-19')
```

Last for output are used `f-string`s:

```
print(f"Number of slots = {up}")
print(f"Number of show up = {no}")
print(f"show up percentage = {up/no*100}")
Number of slots = 5
Number of show up = 8
show up percentage = 62.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a day column, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961892/python-pandas-group-by-day-and-count-for-each-day):

```
df['day'] = df['Appointment'].dt.floor('d')
```

Then you can use boolean indexing:

```
def Doctor_date_summary(Doctor, date):
    number_of_show_up = np.sum((df['Doctor']==Doctor) & (df['day']==date) & (df['Show']=='Yes'))
    number_of_slots = np.sum((df['Doctor']==Doctor) & (df['day']==date))

    return number_of_show_up, number_of_slots, 100*number_of_show_up/number_of_slots
```

Finally:

```
number_of_show_up, number_of_slots, percentage = Doctor_date_summary('A', '2020-01-19')

print("Number of slots = {}".format(number_of_slots))
print("Number of show up = {}".format(number_of_show_up))
print("show up percentage = {:.1f}".format(percentage))

Number of slots = 8
Number of show up = 5
show up percentage = 62.5
```